# Generate random number without range for a given argument for the same length in python be it in numeric or alphanumeric

Tags: python, random

Generate random number without range for a given parameter for the same length in python be it in numeric or alphanumeric

For example :

I pass a numeric value (123456) to my function, then the function should return a random integer number say 876529 for the same length and the characters in the value should not be repeated also the random number should not be repeatable when the function is called multiple times.

the same with alphanumeric: for example, if I pass A2ED8I then the function should return me some alphanumeric value for the same length.

Comment: _I tried a lot of ways to complete_ If you don't post some of that code your question will probably be closed.

Comment: Hi Johnny it was all in an online editor which i did not save them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For strings: Random shuffle of letters A-Z and number 0-9 and
   returns length of input seed
2. For numbers: Shuffles digits 0-9 and converts to a number to return
3. Shuffling is based upon the input (either string or number)

**Code**

```
import random
import string

def rand_gen(seed):
  " Generate random strings and numbers based upon seed "

  # Seed random number generator for shuffling
  random.seed(seed)

  # Alphabet based upon type of input (string or integer)
  if isinstance(seed, int):
    # Result based upon numbers 0-9
    alphabet = string.digits
    seed = str(seed)
    is_int = True
  else:
    # Result uses letters in upon A-Z and 0-9
    alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits
    is_int = False

  # Output based upon random shuffling of alphabet
  x = list(alphabet)
  while True:
    random.shuffle(x)
    if x[0] != '0' or not is_digit:  # Avoid left most digit being 0 for when working with numbers
      break 

  output = ''.join(x[:len(seed)])
  if is_int:
    return int(output)
  else:
    return output
```

**Test**

```
for i in range(1, 15):
  print(f'Numeric Seed: {i:<12} \tString: {rand_gen(i)}')

for i in range(1, 10):
  seed = 'a'*i
  print(f'Charact Seed: {seed:<12} String: {rand_gen(seed)}')
```

**Output**

Output width same as input seed

```
Numeric Seed: 1             String: 6
Numeric Seed: 2             String: 5
Numeric Seed: 3             String: 1
Numeric Seed: 4             String: 8
Numeric Seed: 5             String: 2
Numeric Seed: 6             String: 5
Numeric Seed: 7             String: 8
Numeric Seed: 8             String: 8
Numeric Seed: 9             String: 9
Numeric Seed: 10            String: 52
Numeric Seed: 11            String: 26
Numeric Seed: 12            String: 89
Numeric Seed: 13            String: 30
Numeric Seed: 14            String: 90
Charact Seed: a            String: Q
Charact Seed: aa           String: ZX
Charact Seed: aaa          String: 5DE
Charact Seed: aaaa         String: 3AV7
Charact Seed: aaaaa        String: I2J76
Charact Seed: aaaaaa       String: ZRHENX
Charact Seed: aaaaaaa      String: R17ZXV4
Charact Seed: aaaaaaaa     String: QEGZYTNA
Charact Seed: aaaaaaaaa    String: VDIFQO7SH
```

Comment: Perfect , thank you so much Darry it is working as expected :)

Answer (score 1):

by doing some research I will come with this ugly solution :

First you will generate a list with all ascii character:

```py
value = '1230LE'
t = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789')
```

Then remove from this long string the value character present in your string value (using `t.index` to find the index of the character):

```py
for c in value:
   del t[t.index(c)]
# Output (without '1', '2', '3', '0', 'L', 'E')
# ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','F','G','H','I','J','K','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','4','5','6','7','8','9']
```

Then you only need to do a basic generator based on your new string:

```py
from random import choice
n = len(value)
str_characters = ''.join(t) # 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDFGHIJKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ456789'
generated_value = [choice(str_characters) for i in range(n)] # ['7', 'l', 'N', 'j', 'c', 'i']
''.join(generated_value) #'7lNjci'
```

Here you are, it's a tricky solution but it's working.

If you want to do it for only numeric you can use this value for `t`:

```py
t = list('0123456789')
```

Full code :

```py
value = '1230LE'
t = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789')
for c in value:
   del t[t.index(c)]
from random import choice
n = len(value)
str_characters = ''.join(t) # 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDFGHIJKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ456789'
generated_value = [choice(str_characters) for i in range(n)] # ['7', 'l', 'N', 'j', 'c', 'i']
''.join(generated_value) #'7lNjci'
```

Hope it will help, have fun !

Comment: I edit my answer, I forget to add the argument of choice, which is the new string of characters.. my bad ;)

Answer (score 0):

First, try to check if the input is an integer or if it is alphanumeric. `isinstance()` should help with this.

Based on that decision, you can then choose to generate random numbers or random letters. You can get the length of your input through `len()` (though if it is an integer, you'll have to change it to a different type first).

Randomly generating numbers can be done with the random library.

Randomly generating letters can be done by randomly generating numbers and converting them to letters. Check out `ord()` and `chr()`.